# syntax error when ordering by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm using postgresql for a database on a Rails app that keeps track of when certain events take place. The database column for when the event takes place is called `when` (bad name, I know). I can do this

```
@events = @group.events.order('created_at DESC')
```

However, when I do this

```
 @events = @group.events.order('when DESC')
```

I get this error

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "when"
LINE 1: ..."events"  WHERE "events"."group_id" = $1  ORDER BY when DESC
                                                              ^
: SELECT "events".* FROM "events"  WHERE "events"."group_id" = $1  ORDER BY when DESC
```

A `when` record has this format in the database

```
when: "2013-08-07"
```

Based on what I've told you, can you see the reason why I can't do this

```
@events = @group.events.order('when DESC')
```

It's important for me to be able to order the events by when they are being held. Since ordering by created_at works, I don't see why the syntax error arises when I substitute a different column.

Comment: WHEN is a reserved word in SQL (CASE WHEN clause), try with `.order('events.when DESC')` (but I recommend that you change this column's name) (maybe `start_time` instead of `when`?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- WHEN is a reserved word in SQL (think about the Switch cases: `CASE <smth> WHEN ...`)
- You can try accessing it like this:

  ```
  Event.order('events.when DESC')
  ```
- You should change your column's name to something different than `when` (Take a look at @PhilipHallstrom comment)

Comment: I'd suggest "occurs_at" or "starts_at" (or their _on equivalents if they are dates, not date times) as they fit more nicely with Rails timestamps.

Comment: The usual way around this problem is to double quote the offending identifier (`.order('"when" desc')`) but your third point is the real solution.

Comment: @muistooshort I've been wondering why you haven't answered any of my questions recently